# Ionic side menu: Android and IOS lay-out

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In PhoneGap I'm developing an app with IonicFramework. The app will be build for Android and IOS. These two completely different operating systems have differnt lay-out propperties.

Now, I have set up the app for both lay-outs, but I'm struggeling with the slide-menu. I cant seem to get the right result.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!